# How to display weekly data for given date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display all the data(count) between the given date range in week wise in oracle.

```
Select count(log.end_date) 
  from tablename 
 where log.end_date between '01-Jul-2013' AND '30-Jul-2013'
```

The date range can be between months also like - 01-Jun-2013 to 30-Jul-2013.

How can I display like this?

```
Count    Week

23      wk1 
45      wk2 
67      wk3 
34      wk4 
78      wk5   
and so on....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your definition of a week?

Comment: Week can be from Mon-Sun or Sun-sat it really doesn't matter- can be considered as Mon-Sun, but the count should start from wk1, wk2....so on. Thanks

Comment: How do you define week one?

Comment: Assuming date range as 01-Jun-2013 to 08-Jun-2013 and week as Sun-Sat. The dates 01(wed),02(thu),03(fri),04(sat) falls in first week and dates 05(Sun),06(Mon),07(Tue),08(Wed) falls in second week and so on .....Thanks.

Comment: So Weeks are numbered reative to the first week in the data?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this site and search for `IW (ISO week)`

You can alter your statement to be something like this:

```
SELECT   count(log.end_date) Count,
         to_char( date log.end_date, 'IW' ) Week
FROM     tablename 
WHERE    log.end_date between '01-Jul-2013' AND '30-Jul-2013'
GROUP BY to_char( date log.end_date, 'IW' )
```

EDIT:

Did not take a part of the question into my query. Here is an updated version that substracts the ISO week of the first week and adds one to get wk1, wk2, wk3....

```
SELECT   count(log.end_date) Count,
         'wk' || (1 + to_char( date log.end_date, 'IW' ) - to_char( date '01-Jul-2013', 'IW')) Week
FROM     tablename 
WHERE    log.end_date between '01-Jul-2013' AND '30-Jul-2013'
GROUP BY to_char( date log.end_date, 'IW' )
```

Comment: That displays in the ISO week- week of the year.

Comment: I am getting Invalid number error when trying to execute the edited version.

Comment: Please try different calculations like `to_char( date log.end_date, 'IW' ) - to_char( date '01-Jul-2013', 'IW')` and report what happens

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for to_char with either IW or WW format. You are also looking for the way to group by this week:

```
select count(*), to_char(end_date,'IW')
from tablename 
where trunc(end_date) between to_date('01-07-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('30-07-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
group by to_char(end_date,'IW')
order by to_char(end_date,'IW');
```

From Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm:

> IW Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.
>
> WW Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.

Comment: Just to let you know why I changed the where clause: 1. trunc the date in case it contains a time part (30-Jul-2013 05:00 would not be between 01-Jul-2013 and 30-Jul-2013 for instance). 2. you are relying on Oracle knowing what Jul means. It does on an English database, but may not do so on another (Oct would be Okt on my system here in Germany for example).